# how to validate datetime format

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datetime

I have a textbox for entering date.Textbox should allow only dd/MM/yyyy format.How can i check it using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using dd/mm/yyyy to validate dates -- you can use the JavaScript date object to validate dates but its trickier in this case:

```
var o = document.form1.date1; // o is a reference to the textbox
var r = /^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/.exec( o.value ); // extract day, month and year
if ( ! r )
{
  // invalid date -- pattern matching failed
}
var d = parseInt( r[ 1 ], 10 );
var m = parseInt( r[ 2 ], 10 );
var y = parseInt( r[ 3 ], 10 );
var c = new Date( y, m - 1, d ); // month is zero based but year and day are not
if ( isNaN( c ) )
{
  // invalid date -- javascript could not make a date out of the three numbers
}
```

Comment: You should use the radix argument of the parseInt function, you could have problems *specially* with *date part* numbers which have preceding zeros, for example: `parseInt('08') == 0`. The preceding zero indicates to parseInt that the number being parsed is an octal number, you should use `parseInt(n, 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WebForms, just use a [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtInput" Type="Date"
 Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="That's not a valid date!" />
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, been so long since I did ASP.NET I couldn't remember the Operator property.  Thanks!